# Inserting received unix timestamp as right format in MSSQL Server with node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, unix-timestamp, human-readable

I want to import the unix timestamp (contained in an received Json body) into my MSSQL database as a human readable time using Node.js.

The Json body looks like this:

```
{
  "device":"887B53",
  "data":"4660000000000062b4a8",
  "station":"1B2C",
  "rssi":"-123",
  "time":"1586096200"
}
```

**My question:**

Does MSSQL support a datatype that is used for unix timestamp in order to make it human readable?

If not, how do I format this timestamp before inserting it into my MSSQL server?

I have already tried to format it before importing. But so far I could not find a data type that accepts this format:

```
const time = new Date(request.payload.time *1000)
```

Comment: Isn’t it just a number? Number of seconds since 1970?  Bigint would work

Comment: Yes Int would work too, but then only the number of seconds is displayed and no human readable time.

Comment: You asked about storing it.  If you want to convert it to a SQL date type, I would expect that you can do so by using dateadd https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15